# Capturing screen failed when the active window has an error message box

Tags: perl, winapi, screenshot

I'm writing a software testing framework using `perl` on Windows platform, which run test cases by calling the software under test. If a test case fails, the framework will capture the screen so we could get more information about the failure.

At first I used an small program called `boxcutter-fs.exe`. So all I need is to call this program when test case fails:

```
system("boxcutter-fs.exe screenshot.png");
print "Failed: $?" if ($?);
```

When the framework handles a normal failure, it works great and give me the right failure screenshot. But I noticed that when the software crashed (an error message box would occur on the active window, and the software under test will be killed after a timeout), `boxcutter-fs.exe` exited with code 1, and didn't get any screenshot.

---

Then I turned to other solutions. The first alternative that I tried is `Win32::GuiTest`:

```
eval {
    SendKeys('{PRTSCR}');
    my $screen = Win32::Clipboard::GetBitmap() or die "No image captured: $!\n";
    open    BITMAP, "> screenshot.bmp" or die "Couldn't open bitmap file: $!\n";
    binmode BITMAP;
    print   BITMAP $screen;
    close   BITMAP;
};
print "$@" if ($@);
```

The same result. This works well unless the software crash case occurred. The program reported `No image captured` so I think `Win32::Clipboard::GetBitmap` didn't get any thing in the Clipboard.

---

The last solution is `Imager::Screenshot`:

```
eval {
    my $img = screenshot(hwnd => 'active');
    $img->write(file => 'screenshot.bmp', type => 'bmp' ) 
          or die "Failed: ", $img->{ERRSTR} , "\n";
};
print "$@" if ($@);
```

This time it gave a black screen screenshot (an all-black image) when the software crash case occurs. Still doesn't work.

Then I found that when the crash and error message box occurs, but the software hasn't been killed so the test framework is still hanging, using a small script with any of the solutions above could capture the screenshot. It seems they just fail at the moment when the software under test is being killed.

Since these 3 methods all use Win32 API to get the screenshot, I wonder they might fail due to the same issue? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied the source code of `Imager::Screenshot`, and found the possible cause for the screenshot failure.

First of all, if I use `-d` option of perl to debug the screenshot script, when the software under test crashed and was killed after a timeout, the screenshot worked. So I suppose the screenshot failure should be a corner case in a specific situation.

Then I read the source code of `Imager::Screenshot`. Basically, it's a perl module calling XS extensions written with Win32 APIs. The processing flow is basically as following:

1. Use `GetDC` according to the window handler `hwnd` to get display device context `dc`
2. Use `CreateCompatibleDC` to get the device context handler `hdc`
3. Use `GetDIBits` to retrieve the bits of the device context, and write them to the bmp file

My problem is that when the software under test crashed and was killed, the `hwnd` of its window would be invalid at once, but it was still passed to `GetDC` to get the display device context, thus the result was invalid too (the bmp file was `memset` to all 0 at the beginning, so it's a black screenshot)

---

Now that I noticed the root cause was the invalid `hwnd`, I come up with a work around: take the screenshot before killing the software under test. I used `Proc::Background` and `Win32::GuiTest`. The key point is to ensure the software GUI is set as foreground window:

```
sub captureWindow {
    my ($pid, $screenshot_name) = @_;
    for my $hwnd (&findHwnd($pid)) {
        if (Win32::GuiTest::SetActiveWindow($hwnd) && Win32::GuiTest::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd)) {
            system("boxcutter-fs.exe $screenshot_name");
            # send ALT+TAB key so the script was set back to foreground window
            Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("%{TAB}");
            last;
        }
    }
}

sub findHwnd {
    my ($target_pid) = @_;
    my @target_hwnd;

    EnumWindows(
        Win32::API::Callback->new(sub {
            my ($hwnd, $target_pid) = @_;

            my $pid = 0xffffffff;
            my $tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId($hwnd, $pid);

            $pid = unpack 'L', $pid;

            if ($target_pid == $pid) {
                push @target_hwnd, $hwnd;
            }
            return 1;
        }, 'NN', 'I'),
        $target_pid,
    );

    return @target_hwnd;
}

sub monitorTestProcess {
    my ($cmd, $timeout) = @_;
    my $rs;

    my $proc = Proc::Background->new($cmd);
    my $pid = $proc->pid;

    select(undef, undef, undef, 0.5);
    &captureWindow($pid, "screenshot_begin.png");

    my $timeCount = 0;
    while ($proc->alive) {
        if ($timeCount >= $timeout) {
            &captureWindow($pid, "screenshot_timeout.png");
            $proc->die;
            last;
        }
        select(undef, undef, undef, 1);
        $timeCount++;
    }

    return $rs;
}
```